# discrete metric and limit point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I am having a trouble in understanding why every metric space with discrete metric is perfect.
first we know that neighborhood with discrete metric is either one point or the whole space (depending on if we choose the radius to be greater than 1 or less than and equal 1). so to prove that an arbitrary set is perfect we have to show that every point is limit point and since, neighborhood with radius less than one is just the point itself so we can't tell that point is limit point. can someone please help me.

Comment: "neighborhood with discrete metric is either one point or the whole space" no, since every subset is open.

Comment: can you please elaborate. I couldn't understand @AnneBauval

Comment: Open balls centered around a point are not the only open neighbourhoods of said point. There are many others.

Comment: that's true but my point is neighborhood of every points of said set if has the radius less than or equal one is just a singleton set and nothing more and conditions of every radius doesn't hold for that point to be a limit point. I would be delighted if you can clarify my mistake @Arthur

Comment: And in a discrete space, every point is isolated. So what is your definition of "perfect space" and who told you "every metric space with discrete metric is perfect"?

Comment: Yes, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set) mentions this "b", among others, this is why I asked.

Comment: Note that there are two definitions of *perfect* space: a) = has no isolated point, b) =  every closed subset is $G_\delta$. Both definitions have nothing to do with each other.  Metric spaces are always "b)-perfect", but need not be "a)-perfect" (for instance, non-empty discrete metric space). Might be you mixed up these two definitions?